# Page dimensions using geometry package

Tags: packages, geometry

Long time listener; first time caller here at TEX, so go easy on me. Can someone please tell me if there are any advantages of using

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
```

instead of defining the size in the paper size in the document class

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you are only choosing the paper size, there is no difference.

Comment: @Sigur there may be:-)

Comment: So, the result is not the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default latex knows nothing about the physical paper size (or the size of the window in a pdf viewer) It just sets a text block of specified size indented on the left. So the bottom form relies on your default viewer or printer combination defaulting to A4, however several packages (including at least `hyperref`, `graphics`, `geometry`) set `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` (or equivalent specials with tex engines other than pdftex) which does cause the generated page size to be explicitly A4.